# Sencha touch centered list, is that possible?

Tags: list, extjs, center

[SOLVED] Thanks to Vadym - Sencha has its own margin property, which helped.

I have an Ext.dataview.List which has width: '320px'. What I need to do now is to make these fixed 320px - this list - to be in a center of a screen of any resolution.

Can't show you a picture because of reputation so I will repeat it in another words and do a little sketch.

I need the list to be positioned in the center of the screen.

```
I have it like this now - docked at the left side:
_________________________________________
||list item 1              |             |
||list item 2              |             |
||list item 3              |             |
||list item 4              |             |


What I want to accomplish is this - centered in the middle:
_________________________________________
|      |list item 1             |       |
|      |list item 2             |       |
|      |list item 3             |       |
|      |list item 4             |       |
```

I found a config value of a list that I thought could do the job - centered - but when I set this value to true, the list disappears completely.

My code is just this:

```
Ext.define('GeoFun.view.Ukoly', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'ukolylist',
    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    config: {
        ui: 'round',
        width: '320px',
        //centered: true, -- doesn't work  
        itemTpl:  Ext.create(
            'Ext.XTemplate',  
            '<div class="listItemContainer">',
            '    I need this list to be in center of the screen.',
            '</div>')
    
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha has its own margin property, which helped.

```
Ext.define('GeoFun.view.Ukoly', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'ukolylist',
    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    config: {
        ui: 'round',
        width: '320px',

        margin: 0 auto; //<-- solution

        itemTpl:  Ext.create(
            'Ext.XTemplate',  
            '<div class="listItemContainer">',
            '    I need this list to be in center of the screen.',
            '</div>')

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Sencha has any properties that will do the job. 
So you should just do it by css. Define next css rule:

```
.listcontainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or, at least, use inline style

Comment: I may have written it a bit confusing. listcontainer is a container for an item of the list - i will edit it right away. So this margin doesn't apply on the whole list. I tried it and it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sencha actually has margin property, which did the trick! Thanks

Comment: really. forgot about margins-property :)